# Compiling gstreamer with msdkh264enc results in relocation errors

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I would like to use `msdkh264enc` (on Linux) which requires that I build gstreamer from sources, as per [the docs](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer#building-the-intel-msdk-plugin).

I run the following configure step:

```
meson setup -Dbad=enabled -Dgst-plugins-bad:msdk=enabled -Dgst-plugins-bad:avtp=disabled build
```

Which enables `msdk` (that's the point here) and disables `avtp` (because it fails to build on my Alpine Linux).

The configure step works and shows the [required output](https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK/wiki/Build-GStreamer-MSDK#build-gstreamer-plugins-bad)

```
Run-time dependency libmfx found: YES 1.28
Has header "mfx/mfxdefs.h" : YES 
Has header "mfxvp9.h" : YES
```

At the end of the build I install in `/tmp/blah` with:

```
meson install --destdir /tmp/blah -C build
```

I have a `libgstmsdk.so`, but its `ldd libgstmsdk.so` output looks like there are runtime issues:

```
ldd /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so                                                                                                                                                                            [0]
    /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f33e7666000)
    libgstbase-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 (0x7f33e75a2000)
    libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x7f33e7457000)
    libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 (0x7f33e7393000)
    libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 (0x7f33e7354000)
    libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0 (0x7f33e72ca000)
    libgstva-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstva-1.0.so.0 (0x7f33e72b6000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x7f33e716a000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x7f33e710d000)
    libmfx.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmfx.so.1 (0x7f33e70fd000)
    libva.so.2 => /usr/lib/libva.so.2 (0x7f33e70d3000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0x7f33e70bd000)
    libgudev-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgudev-1.0.so.0 (0x7f33e70b2000)
    libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f33e7666000)
    libintl.so.8 => /usr/lib/libintl.so.8 (0x7f33e70a0000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x7f33e7099000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x7f33e701b000)
    libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 (0x7f33e6f9c000)
    libgsttag-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 (0x7f33e6f5e000)
    libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 (0x7f33e6f57000)
    libva-drm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libva-drm.so.2 (0x7f33e6f52000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x7f33e6eab000)
    libffi.so.8 => /usr/lib/libffi.so.8 (0x7f33e6ea1000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7f33e6c08000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7f33e6be4000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/libudev.so.1 (0x7f33e6bd4000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7f33e6bba000)
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_va_dmabuf_get_modifier_for_format: symbol not found
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_video_info_dma_drm_to_video_info: symbol not found
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_video_dma_drm_fourcc_from_string: symbol not found
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_video_info_dma_drm_new_from_caps: symbol not found
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_video_dma_drm_fourcc_to_string: symbol not found
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_video_info_dma_drm_init: symbol not found
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_video_info_dma_drm_to_caps: symbol not found
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_video_is_dma_drm_caps: symbol not found
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_va_drm_fourcc_from_video_format: symbol not found
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_video_info_dma_drm_free: symbol not found
Error relocating /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so: gst_va_video_format_from_drm_fourcc: symbol not found
```

Note how e.g. `libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0`, which is the system libgstreamer, where it should actually be pointing to `libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => ./subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/sys/msdk/../../../gstreamer/gst/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0`!

If I `ldd ./subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/sys/msdk/libgstmsdk.so` (so the library *before* it gets installed), it seems fine. But I need to install all those binaries in order to use them (I can't reasonably point GST_PLUGIN_PATH to each separate build directory)!

What am I doing wrong in the installation step?

Comment: Sounds like you compiled the plugin with a different version than you have on your system. It uses newer symbols from a Gst version which your system Gst apparently does not have.

Comment: But I just compiled and installed gstreamer *from source*... why would it pick up anything on the system? But you're right that if I `ldd /tmp/blah/usr/local/bin/gst-inspect-1.0`, it points to `libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0` instead of `/tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0`...

Comment: Aha! Before installation, gst-inspect-1.0 seems to be pointing to the right place: `ldd ./subprojects/gstreamer/tools/gst-inspect-1.0` shows `libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => ./subprojects/gstreamer/tools/../gst/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0` and libgstmsdk.so is fine, too. So `meson install --destdir /tmp/blah` seems to screw things up... Let me update my question with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not about how meson installs the binaries, but rather it has to do with the dynamic linking at runtime. I am no sure if there is a better solution, but setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` works here:

```
% LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/blah/usr/local/lib ldd /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmsdk.so        [0]
    /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f7117484000)
    libgstbase-1.0.so.0 => /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 (0x7f71173be000)
    libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x7f7117266000)
    libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 => /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 (0x7f711718e000)
    libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 => /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 (0x7f711714b000)
    libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0 => /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0 (0x7f71170b7000)
    libgstva-1.0.so.0 => /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/libgstva-1.0.so.0 (0x7f71170a1000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x7f7116f55000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x7f7116ef8000)
    libmfx.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmfx.so.1 (0x7f7116ee8000)
    libva.so.2 => /usr/lib/libva.so.2 (0x7f7116ebe000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0x7f7116ea8000)
    libgudev-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgudev-1.0.so.0 (0x7f7116e9d000)
    libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f7117484000)
    libintl.so.8 => /usr/lib/libintl.so.8 (0x7f7116e8b000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x7f7116e84000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x7f7116dce000)
    libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 => /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 (0x7f7116d47000)
    libgsttag-1.0.so.0 => /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 (0x7f7116d06000)
    libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 => /tmp/blah/usr/local/lib/libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 (0x7f7116cfd000)
    libva-drm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libva-drm.so.2 (0x7f7116cf8000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x7f7116c51000)
    libffi.so.8 => /usr/lib/libffi.so.8 (0x7f7116c47000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7f71169ae000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7f711698a000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/libudev.so.1 (0x7f711697a000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7f7116960000)
```